# Using gdb to debug C program, but it cannot locate source file correctly

Tags: c, gdb

I use the command `gcc -std=gnu99 -g -pthread dotProduct_critical_ompi.c -I.` to compile my C program and then use gdb to debug it with the command `gdb dotproduct`.

But the source file which gdb shows in terminal named `dotProduct_critical.c` is not the source file I compiled ( my source file is `dotProduct_critical_ompi.c` ). Why? Thanks for your help.

[image: the information in terminal]

**Update**

The problem was solved after I remove the output file and recompile several times. But today, after I modified my source file, the error occured once more. And the method doesn't work any more. What can I do? (My source file is still `dotProduct_critical_ompi.c`)

[image]

> the output of command `gdb -batch dotproduct -ex "info sources"` is:

[image]

Comment: make sure that you're debugging the executable that you compiled, not another one. Change the dest name (don't use `a.out` which sucks). Use `-o dotproduct` for instance then debug with `gdb dotproduct`

Comment: ok, then remove your `a.out` file, recompile, and tell us.

Comment: it's not possible that the compiler substituted `dotProduct_critical_ompi.c` by `dotProduct_critical.c`. Is your file a symlink?

Comment: What is the output of `gdb -batch a.out -ex "info sources"`?

Comment: What arguments are you giving to gdb? Can you show all the output that gdb produces (you can omit the copyright notice) from the very beginning?